# Keep getting "Account authentication error" in xcode

Tags: xcode

I have been getting this yellow cloud (Photo attached), that states I am not signed into my account. However, I am when it comes to checking out the accounts page in the general tab of xcode.
I know it is newbie thing, but for the life of me, cannot figure out why it is happening.

My GitHub is also linked, as I have been committing my code.

When I go to "my certificates", my certification is listed, by there is no status under the "status" column heading.

I have signed out. Removed all instances of xcode in keychain. Asked to sign in again, did so - and still met with the authentication error.

Double checked Apple ID and password, both correct.

Is there another reason this may be happening that I am unaware of?

I have signed out. Removed all instances of xcode in keychain. Asked to sign in again, did so - and still met with the authentication error.
Double checked Apple ID and password, both correct.
Thought it may be an initial login error, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering, it seems to be a bug with 14.2
Apple forums have numerous cases of the same instance.
I just dismiss the notification for now, and all seems to work perfectly fine.

Hope this helps anyone that may be going through the same issue.

Comment: Could you add links or quotes from the other posts/forums you are referencing?

Comment: @Ace.C Here is one for you that has no response from Apple till date: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/728563